# Force code review of a team member - EGit

Tags: egit

I have a repository in GitHub and I connected it to my eclipse git.

Now I want to share it with my friends so we can update the code together.

The problem is that every one of my friends can push anything to the remote master without supervision.

I want to force one of my team members to approve a commit before she gets pushed to the master, like code review or something.

What are my options and how can I accomplish them ?

Thanks,
ben

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, GitHub uses pull request for code review and code merge. If your friends want to push code, they should first fork your repository, push code to their forked repository and create pull request for review.